# c++: convert string to hexadecimal byte array?

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, mbed

I am using the mbed microcontroller and programming in c++. I have a string that contains JSON data. How do I convert the JSON string to a hexadecimal byte array to then later encrypt the data using AES128 and also pad the JSON string if need be? Also, how do I convert a hexadecimal byte array to ascii?

I am working with this c++ example:

```
#include "mbed.h"
#include "Crypto.h"

Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
unsigned char myKEY[16] = {0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F,};
unsigned char myIV[16] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, } ;
unsigned char msg[0x60] =
{
    0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 
    0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 0xAA, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
    0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 0x55, 
    0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
} ;
int main()
{
    pc.baud (115200);
    pc.printf("\r\nCleartext");
    for(char i=0; i<0x60; i++) 
    {
        if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",msg[i]);
    }

    // init crypto
    //AES myAES(AES_128, myKEY); // will default to ECB_MODE
    //AES myAES(AES_128, myKEY, myIV); // will default to CBC_MODE
    AES myAES(AES_128, myKEY, myIV, PCBC_MODE); // specify all params, look at BlockCipher.h for modes
    pc.printf("\r\n\r\nFirst run\r\n");
    myAES.encrypt(msg,msg,0x60); // same in and out buffer can be used
    pc.printf("\r\nEncrypted");
    for(char i=0; i<0x60; i++) 
    {
        if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",msg[i]);
    }
    pc.printf("\r\nDecrypted again");
    myAES.decrypt(msg,msg,0x60);
    for(char i=0; i<0x60; i++) 
    {
        if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",msg[i]);
    }
    // change key and IV without reinit all
    unsigned char newKey[16];
    unsigned char newIV[16];
    memset(newKey, 0x22, 16);
    memset(newIV, 0x33, 16);
    myAES.keyExpansion(newKey);
    myAES.setIV(newIV);
    pc.printf("\r\n\r\nKey and IV changed\r\n");
    unsigned char plaintext[0x60];
    unsigned char ciphertext[0x60];
    myAES.encrypt(ciphertext,msg,0x60); // different buffers if you have space
    pc.printf("\r\nEncrypted");
    for(char i=0; i<0x60; i++) 
    {
        if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",ciphertext[i]);
    }
    pc.printf("\r\nDecrypted again");
    myAES.decrypt(plaintext,ciphertext,0x60); // different buffers if you have space
    for(char i=0; i<0x60; i++) 
    {
        if(i%16==0) pc.printf("\r\n");
        pc.printf("%.2X",plaintext[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Encryption does not work "in hex", it works on *numbers*. So you'll be happy to learn that a string is actually nothing more than a list of numbers.

Comment: @Jongware Well, that makes sense because when I added an 'a' into the msg char array I received a 61.  I looked up '61' in an ASCII chart, I noticed 61 represents 'a'.  What through me off is the the 0xAA and 0x55. The pc.printf outputs 'AA' and '55'.  I looked at 0xAA and 0x55 in a Hex conversion chart and I didn't get back 'AA' or '55'.  I don't understand what 0xAA and 0x55 are supposed to represent?

Comment: I also did:  `unsigned char msg[96] =
{
    '{', '"', 'a', 'r', 'r', 'a', 'y', ':', '[', '1', ',', '2', ',', '3', ']', ',', '"', 'b', 'o','o', 'l', 'e', 'a', 'n', '"', ':', 't', 'r', 'u', 'e', '}',
};`  
  
 which results to these Hex values:  7B2261727261793A5B312C322C335D2C
22626F6F6C65616E223A747275657D
  
I manually went through the list of Hex values and converted the characters using a Hex converter I found on a website and the result was a direct representative of my original char array.  With a little more experimenting I should better understand how all this works.